# Failed at AJAX POST request to the same page (with example)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

### Codes

```
####### The name of this file is 'test_ajaxfn.php' #######
<?php
if($_POST['var']) {
    $result = $_POST['var'];
    echo $result.' is successfully passed to the same page using Ajax Post. :)';    
} else {
    echo 'There is no POST variable passed to the same page. :( ';  
}

echo '<br> Above indicates the ajax post function \'.\' ';
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clickdiv').click(function() {
        var sth = "value to send to PHP";
        $.post(
        'test_ajaxfn.php',
        {"var":"1234567"},
        function(){
            alert('success');
            $('#clickdiv').text('the POST variable should be posted.');
        }
        );

    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="clickdiv" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background:#CC3300; cursor:pointer;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Description

I want to pass POST variable to the same page and load it using AJAX. However, I failed to do so. I can't pass the "var" to $_POST['var'] using POST method. Hence I can't display the following:
    echo $result.' is successfully passed to the same page using Ajax Post. :)';

What have I done wrong?

### Reference

I was actually trying to tackle this problem:
[Calculate Google distance of Input address and all the address from MySQL Server using jQuery ajax.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914506/calculate-google-distance-of-input-address-and-all-the-address-from-mysql-server)
Now I simplify my problem but still it doesn't work. Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you post it to the same page the server creates a new process to handle the request.  The reason you are not seeing any output is because the server is seeing a post to a file, spinning up an instance and executing the php script but that is different from your php thread.  Change your script to this to see your success text.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clickdiv').click(function() {
        var sth = "value to send to PHP";
        $.post(
        'test_ajaxfn.php',
        {"var":"1234567"},
        function(result){
            alert(result);
            $('#clickdiv').text('the POST variable should be posted.');
        }
        );

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response! I have tried to change the code according to your suggestion.

However, I got the success text in a pop-up box, plus the whole HTML code in the popup box as well.

"1234567 is successfully passed to the same page using Ajax Post. :)<br> Above indicates the ajax post function '.' 

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<he....." <--- yes, all the codes were in the popup box as well..

Comment: And moreover, the page still doesn't change to success text. It is still "there is no Post variable passed to the same page :(".

Comment: Well good job doing that now go ahead and add if(if($_POST['var'])){exit();} above your last echo.

Comment: @ChrisYeung "And moreover, the page still doesn't change to success text"  you will only see your version of the website changing if you change it with javascript after its already loaded.

Comment: @" if(if($_POST['var'])){exit();} above your last echo" - I don't seem to be able to add that.. there's some sort of syntax error..

Comment: "only see your version of the website changing.." - Does that mean I won't be able to change what was already loaded on the page?

Comment: Sorry this should be better if($_POST['var'])){exit();}  -- also if you want to change your version which was already loaded use javascript. You would take the text you are seeing, the variable called "result" in the callback and then make its text equal to the var "response". Like this. $(".div-i-want").text(response);

Comment: Thanks for the help. The reason I want to test the ajax.post functionality on the same page is because of the more complicated problem I am having [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914506/calculate-google-distance-of-input-address-and-all-the-address-from-mysql-server). I can't do it with Javascript because i don't want to pass sensitive data from the MySQL database to JS. Therefore I want to do it on the server-side and then update on the same page. However, it seems it's not possible..

Comment: ' if($_POST['var'])){exit();}' - do you mean if($_POST['var']){exit();}? And do I put it above echo '<br> Above indicates the ajax post function '?

Comment: @ChrisYeung I'm not quite sure what you changed there. And yes to "do I put it above echo '<br> "

Comment: @ChrisYeung   Also I'm sure if you critically evaluate what a user can do I'm sure your security concerns, while valid, are not actual problems.  Because no matter if you do it server side or client side you will still have to display information to the user.  So for example your sending data here on your other problem:  var data = 'lat='+loc.lat()+'&lng='+loc.lng(); This is not sensitive information and is something the user will be able to find anyways.